# How I can configure Wordpress CMS in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-15.10, visual-studio-code

I have installed [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) on **Ubuntu 15.10** and I need this to recognize all features of Wordpress-Plugins to develop and / or themes of Wordpress.

I want to be alone in the project wordpress plugins developed. I have not found a way to recognize me internal functions.

*Note:* I have more than one developing plugins so I need to have the plugins as separate projects without having to be developed with all the wordpress CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tungvn.wordpress-snippet
or

```
ext install wordpress-snippet
```

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.